# How do I sort the filenames for a dataset, I got the names using glob.glob('path/*.png')

Tags: python, file

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcImH.png)

Hi! I am trying to load the dataset. I want to get the filenames sorted as 1,2,3,...
But I am getting them as 1, 10,100,1000,... as you can see in the images. How should I get it done?

```
filenames = glob.glob("/content/path/train/*.png")
filenames.sort()
images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in filenames]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted as 1,2,3,..."?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `conv-neural-network`, or `cv2` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that IS alphabetical order...  If you know the names are all numeric, then you can supply a `key` function to `.sort()` that uses the ordering you want.

```
def bynumber(fn):
    return int(os.path.basename(fn)[:-4])
...
filenames.sort( key=bynumber )
```

Alternatively:

```
filenames.sort( key=lambda fn: int(os.path.basename(fn)[:-4]) )
```

Comment: in my opinion this is the sort of thing that you could us a lambda for

Comment: You're correct, I thought it was going to be longer than it ended up being.  I was going to use splitext, which would have made it awkwardly long.